# LINQ create multiple new entities using a single ID field

Tags: linq

I have a newbie LINQ question. I need to create two objects of same type from a list of strings. I need to append a text 'Direct' & "Indirect' to the string and use them as ID to create the two unique objects.

```
var vStrings = new List { "Milk", "Eggs", "Cheese" };

var vProducts = (from s in vStrings
                select new Product { ID = s + "-Direct" })
                .Union(
                 from s in vStrings
                select new Product { ID = s + "-InDirect" });
```

You can see in the example above, I am using a Union to create two different objects, Is there a better way to rewrite this LINQ query?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I would not do it this way. Now you iterate twice over your list of strings. Maybe not a point when the list is short, but anyway, I would do it in one simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever needed more suffixes, this might be a better way:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "Milk", "Eggs", "Cheese" };
var suffixes = new List<string> {"-Direct", "-InDirect"};

var products = strings
    .SelectMany(_ => suffixes, (x, y) => new Product() {ID = x + y});
```

And it would only iterate over the original set of strings once.

Answer (score 1):

This way isn't much shorter but I think it would be a little better such as there is only one Concat instead of many Union:

```
var vProducts2 = (from s in vStrings
                  select s + "-Direct").Concat(
                  from s in vStrings
                  select s + "-InDirect");
```